# Retrieving calls history from Windows 10 app - Access denied error

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, phone-call, windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to collect the Windows Mobile 10 calls history by using the latest API. I have enabled all possible capabilities for my application, but still I'm getting "Access Denied" error while running this code:

```
var operation = PhoneCallHistoryManager.RequestStoreAsync(PhoneCallHistoryStoreAccessType.AppEntriesReadWrite);
operation.Completed = (o, ev) =>
{
    PhoneCallHistoryStore store = o.GetResults();
    PhoneCallHistoryEntryReader reader = store.GetEntryReader();

    var operation2 = reader.ReadBatchAsync();
    operation2.Completed = (o2, ev2) =>
    {
        IReadOnlyList<PhoneCallHistoryEntry> callsList = o2.GetResults();
        foreach (PhoneCallHistoryEntry entry in callsList)
        {
            // process calls here
        }
    };
};
```

I'm getting the following error message while doing line 4:

```
An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in App1.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

I'm running this code on Mobile Emulator in Visual Studio 2015.
This is what I used for that code:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.calls.aspx

Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: Are you running VS2015 as Administrator?

Comment: Yes. I think it should not have any effect here, as application is being executed by Mobile Emulator. Checked with "Local Machine" debug mode and I'm receiving the same error.

Comment: Please be more specific when you say "all possible capabilities". The relevant capability is [phoneCallHistory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt270968#special_and_restricted_capabilities).

Comment: Yes, you're right @RaymondChen. I have added all general use capabilities which are available from Manifest editor interface. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make above code working and view phone call history, need to add the following things:

1) Rescap namespace

```
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
```

2) Restricted capability "phoneCallHistory"

```
<rescap:Capability Name="phoneCallHistory"/>
```

3) Change PhoneCallHistoryAccessType to AllEntriesLimitedReadAndWrite.

```
var operation = PhoneCallHistoryManager.RequestStoreAsync(PhoneCallHistoryStoreAccessType.AllEntriesLimitedReadWrite);
```

Thanks to @RaymondChen for giving me the proper capability name.